# Phantomjs meta refresh redirects

Tags: phantomjs

When a page have meta refresh redirect, I can't get the content of page it was redirected to. Even if I use setTimeout and wait 10 seconds to be sure that the last page is loaded, when I do page.content I get the content of the page before redirect.

Is there is something I can do about it?

Here is my code:

```
var mainUrl = "http://t.mobitrk.com/?a=t&aff_id=233&tags=df0a14a1-e673-4082-80c1-5283f4daa11cx&o_id=4879&sub_id=34753&sub_param1=xapnt20iix";


function makeRequest(url) {
    var page = require('webpage').create();
    page.settings.userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; Nexus 5 Build/LMY48I) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.84 Mobile Safari/537.36";

    page.onNavigationRequested = function(url, type, willNavigate, main) {
        console.log(url);
    }


    page.open(url, function (status) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(page.content);
            phantom.exit(0);
        }, 10000);
    });
}


makeRequest(mainUrl);
```

The result is:

```
http://t.mobitrk.com/?a=t&aff_id=233&tags=df0a14a1-e673-4082-80c1-5283f4daa11cx&o_id=4879&sub_id=34753&sub_param1=xapnt20iix
http://app.appsflyer.com/com.groboot.yala?af_prt=fatal2&pid=clicksmob_int&clickid=cB_1448464013_76df1e4d78bf14572c7fe12cafb39f4d_wP&af_siteid=233&advertising_id=&af_sub1=34753
market://details?id=com.groboot.yala&referrer=af_tranid%3DC8KDGS5KXJ5BEQQ%26clickid%3DcB_1448464013_76df1e4d78bf14572c7fe12cafb39f4d_wP%26af_prt%3Dfatal2%26af_siteid%3D233%26pid%3Dclicksmob_int%26af_sub1%3D34753%26advertising_id%3D
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://app.appsflyer.com/com.groboot.yala?af_prt=fatal2&amp;pid=clicksmob_int&amp;clickid=cB_1448464013_76df1e4d78bf14572c7fe12cafb39f4d_wP&amp;af_siteid=233&amp;advertising_id=&amp;af_sub1=34753"></head><body></body></html>
```

As you can see, the page.content contains the content of the first link.

Comment: Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-1_phantomerrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: I've added all this error logs, now the output contains also: Unable to load resource (#3URL:market://details?id=com.groboot.yala&referrer=af_tranid%3D3TP81PQQCB4KVV7X%26clickid%3DcA_1448531194_f4688949b898565ecec8dea1e80911ce_WC%26af_prt%3Dfatal2%26af_siteid%3D233%26pid%3Dclicksmob_int%26af_sub1%3D34753%26advertising_id%3D)
Error code: 301. Description: Protocol "market" is unknown

Comment: The new output is quite logical, but still I don't understand why page.content contains content of the first page instead of second. The phantomjs version is 2.0. I was unable to compile the latest version from git.

Comment: Your guess is as good as mine.

Comment: @offline15 Did you ever find a fix for this?